# Many to many с одной и той же моделью

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть таблица warehouses и сущность warehouse, у сущности warehouse может быть несколько партнеров таких же как он сам, вот так:

```
public class Warehouse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountGate { get; set; }
    public decimal Standart { get; set; }
    public decimal Normal { get; set; }
    public List<Warehouse> FrendlyWarehouses { get; set; }

    public Warehouse()
    {
        FrendlyWarehouses = new List<Warehouse>();
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае, я получаю ошибки ссылки на самого себя, если я в складе 1 укажу на склад 2, а во 2 укажу на 1. Выход я вижу многие ко многим, если бы вручную в SQL я бы создал таблицу с двумя столбцами WarehouseId, FrendlyWarehouseId. Как мне это сделать с EF Core?

Пытаюсь вот так:

```
public class Warehouse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountGate { get; set; }
    public decimal Standart { get; set; }
    public decimal Normal { get; set; }
    public List<WarehouseFrendlyWarehouse> FrendlyWarehouses { get; set; }

    public Warehouse()
    {
        FrendlyWarehouses = new List<WarehouseFrendlyWarehouse>();
    }
}  
public class WarehouseFrendlyWarehouse
{
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public int FrendlyWarehouseId { get; set; }

    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
    public Warehouse FrendlyWarehouse { get; set; }
}
```

Во время миграции получаю ошибку:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Warehouse.FrendlyWarehouses' of type
>   'List'. Either manually configure the
>   relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
>   attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Как правильно поступить, дайте пожалуйста совет.

**Дополнил**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseFrendly>()
    .HasKey(pr => new { pr.WarehouseId, pr.FrendlyWarehouseId });

modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseFrendly>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.FrendlyWarehouse)
    .WithMany(p => p.FrendlyWarehouses)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.FrendlyWarehouseId);

modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseFrendly>()
    .HasOne(pr => pr.Warehouse)
    .WithMany(r => r.FrendlyWarehouses)
    .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.WarehouseId);
```

Comment: Используйте промежуточную таблицу, где в одном столбце будет идентификатор склада, а во второй идентификатор "дружественного" склада. Но для этого нужно будет добавить дополнительную сущность, так как на данный момент EF Core не может создавать many-to-many без создания дополнительной сущности как в "классическом" EF.

Comment: @XelaNimed я так и хотел сделать, посмотрите пожалуйста на код, который я привел, там дополнительная сущность где всё как вы описали, но получаю ошибку.

Comment: Так в ошибке-же всё указано... Вам нужно во FluentAPI указать что к чему соотносится. Приведите Ваш FluentAPI.

Comment: @XelaNimed посмотрите пожалуйста, я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Всё равно не могу понять, где соотношения WarehouseFrendlyWarehouse? Я мог уже чего-то позабыть, но мне думается, что это WarehouseFrendlyWarehouse должен указывать на Warehouse. Или я не прав?